# Is there a way to prevent the ThreadPool from making garbage?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Executing multithreaded methods make garbage. Why is that and can we prevent it?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callBack, state);
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
By garbage I mean objects that are created and then went out of scope. The garbage collection is very slow because of it's old version of mono. So every kb you save from the GC is a win. If you are not familiar with the unity engine, In the screenshot please see The GC column on the highlighted row. It says 0.6kb. Therefore it create 600 bytes of garbage. The callback code is not creating any garbage so this is rooted from ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

**EDIT 2:** To elaborate further here is a more concrete example:

```
public class TestThread : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Time.frameCount%10 == 0)
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DummyMethod);
    }

    public void DummyMethod(object meaningless)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the result. Please look at the highlighted row. The GC column says 285Bytes. Since DummyMethod is not doing anything, the garbage is related to ThreadPool.

[image]

**Edit 3:**
To relax the situation and find an alternative, it would be acceptable to have a worker thread that executes jobs from a queue.

It would be OK But it **MUST** run on CPU other than the one unity uses if there are multiple CPUs available. Unity does nearly anything in a single thread so a background worker on the same CPU would be a disaster. Also it is a cross platform project so windows-only solutions won't work. So basically I need a worker thread solution and to know if it possible to realize if a thread's CPU is the same as another thread's.

Comment: "Make garbage"? What does that mean?

Comment: Doing pretty much *anything* will create garbage that will later need cleanup. In general though, multi-threading means overhead. It's the nature of the beast.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I mean out of scope objects eligible for GC.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Well, This is a unity game so preventing garbage creation is very important. On our project We recycle every object so no garbage is created.

Comment: 17 kb gc allocated. is that a problem?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Without any code showing what you are actually doing in those threads, I'm not sure how you think the question is going to be answerable.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Are. That's a huge problem

Comment: If 17kb really is an issue, you could try not to use the ThreadPool, but directly create threads yourself. Possibly implement your own garbage-free(TM) thread pool ?

Comment: I don't think the GC is the source of your slowness issues.

Comment: @MarkO I would appreciate if it was possible to reuse threads without threadpool

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The code is pretty fast. The problem is with unity's GC slownes. When GC triggers a Collect, It literally freezes the game for some hundred milliseconds and destroys user experience. It is a general practice to lower garbage collection as much as possible

Comment: @mortezakhosravi It is certainly possible. At a high level: create a queue of tasks to be done and add your work to it. Keep one (or several) threads trying to consume the tasks from the queue. Essentially you are re-implementing the thread pool though.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot You mean a thread with an infinite loop and a call to Sleep() when there is no work?

Comment: Use [Object Pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) perhaps?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes the objects in our project are pooled. This is one of the few situations that can't be pooled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DummyMethod);` it actually is implicitly turning your code in to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DummyMethod));`, that callback may be the item that is getting put on to the GC. Try the following code to explicitly create the delegate and keep a reference to it and see if it reduces the amount of GCable data.

```
public class TestThread : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly WaitCallback _callback;

    public TestThread()
    {
        _callback = new WaitCallback(DummyMethod);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Time.frameCount%10 == 0)
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_callback);
    }

    public void DummyMethod(object meaningless)
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a extremely basic implementation of a single threaded background worker, to give you a starting point. The below code is untested and may perform horribly, but it does give you an idea as a starting point.

```
public class BasicBackgroundWorker
{
    private readonly Thread _backgroundWorkThread;
    private readonly Queue<Action> _queue = new Queue<Action>();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _workAvailable = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public BasicBackgroundWorker()
    {
        _backgroundWorkThread = new Thread(BackgroundThread)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal,
            Name = "BasicBackgroundWorker Thread"
        };
        _backgroundWorkThread.Start();
    }

    public void EnqueueWork(Action work)
    {
        lock (_queue)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(work);
            _workAvailable.Set();
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _workAvailable.WaitOne();
            Action workItem;
            lock (_queue)
            {
                workItem = _queue.Dequeue();
                if (_queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    _workAvailable.Reset();
                }
            }
            try
            {
                workItem();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception that happened in backgroundWork
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That helped 16 bytes. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can get any better while still using `QueueUserWorkItem`, any other improvements would require writing a custom Thread Pool you write yourself.

Comment: Have any thought about the EDIT 3 of the post? It would be extremely desireable to have a custom thread pool if it is possible to compare thread CPUs. I could really be relieved that other threads have zero impact on the main thread. That would be far better than using C#'s ThreadPool

Comment: Does Unity let you do `new Thread(WorkerMethod) { IsBackground = true };`? If so you could set up a dedicated background worker that pulled from a `BlockingCollection<T>` of work.

Comment: Yes unity supports .net framework 3.5. It can do it. The only problem is I can't know if the background thread is on the same cpu as the main thread. I will try to find a solution for cross platform thread affinity because I don't want the background thread to race with unity's main thread. Then the background thread you mentioned will be the prefect solution.

Comment: You should not care about what CPU it is on. Just set the Thread Priority to low. The UI thread runs on all CPUs it jumps from CPU to CPU as context switches happen, it does not have a CPU affinity. Forcing it to be "not on the same CPU" would also cause your code to not run at all on single core machines.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a very basic background worker for you to use as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for getting into the trouble of providing the code. It's a good starting point. I'll try and test this and provide feedback.

Comment: You were right. There is not point in finding out wich CPU a thread is running on. The OS changes cpu as it likes. Very good point and thanks again