# Need strategy for multithreading in unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

My unity project is a procedural environment on **Android** and creates terrains and stuff at runtime. The overall workflow I use is to calculate anything **non-unity** in a worker thread and when the data is calculated, I call Unity API within the main thread.

The problem is that **sometimes** (like every 200 frames) the worker thread affects the main thread's performance. That could show itself with a nasty spike in rendering time.

So what to do with multithreading in unity?

**EDIT:** The android device is quad core.

**EDIT 2:** I believe what Sam said in the comments is exactly what's happening.

> I wonder if you can determine what core the code is running on, or if
>   you can set the thread affinity? I found some links where people
>   described similar situations: [here](http://miss-cache.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/android-running-native-code-on-multiple.html) and [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/12a8vdge4t/4-pthreads-same-performance-as-1-pthread-other-cores-not-utilized-tegra-3). Sounds like
>   it's picking the same core as the main thread occasionally.

So maybe this is not about unity but **every real time interactive multithreaded application**. I believe it is possible to set thread affinity on some versions of some platforms but that destroys the cross platform status of the system.

**PS:** Not exactly the main issue but to make the question more concrete, I will include the worker thread implementation. It is a modified version of the worker thread implementation suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813146/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-threadpool-from-making-garbage/34815483?noredirect=1#comment57375687_34815483). The modified version is like this:

```
public static class JobScheduler
{
private static Queue<Job> Jobs = new Queue<Job>();
private static volatile bool isBusy;
private static ManualResetEvent _workAvailable = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static JobScheduler()
{
    var backgroundWorkThread = new Thread(BackgroundThread)
    {
        IsBackground = true,
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest,
        Name = "BasicBackgroundWorker Thread"
    };
    backgroundWorkThread.Start();
}

private static void BackgroundThread()
{
    int jobCnt;
    while (true)
    {
        Job? workItem=null;
        lock (Jobs)
        {
            jobCnt = Jobs.Count;
            if (jobCnt != 0 && !isBusy)
            {
                workItem = Jobs.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        if (workItem!=null)
        {
            isBusy = true;
            workItem.Value.callback(workItem.Value.param);
        }
        else
        {
            _workAvailable.WaitOne();
            _workAvailable.Reset();
        }
    }
}
public static void AddJob(Job Job)
{
    lock (Jobs)
    {
            Jobs.Enqueue(Job);
    }
        _workAvailable.Set();
}

public static void JobDone()
{
    isBusy = false;
    _workAvailable.Set();
}

}
```

And the Job struct:

```
public struct Job
{
public object param;
public WaitCallback callback;
public Job(WaitCallback callBackP
    , object parameter)
{
    callback = callBackP;
    param = parameter;
}
}
```

Whenever needed I call `JobScheduler.AddJob` to enqueue a job and call `JobScheduler.JobDone` after the job is done to allow the next job to run.

Also the ThreadPool is not an option since it produces unnecessary garbage and is not very flexible to use.

Comment: Well why does it affect the main thread? Does the main thread send off a job, then wait for that job to finish? The main thread shouldn't be waiting for the background thread, or else that defeats the purpose of the background thread.

Comment: No the main thread does not wait for any job done. The main thread calls JobScheduler.AddJob to enque some job and continues its job without any interruption. The jobs will be processed in the background thread and after they complete they put their data on another queue. The main thread dequeues some processed data every frame and uses them. So basically the background worker is completely transparent to the main thread.

Comment: What if the queue is empty when the main thread is dequeuing? Will it wait until there is something in the queue?

Comment: No. it dequeues the processed data if there is any. I suspect it is an issue of OS thread timeslicing and the spike happens when worker thread runs on the same cpu as the main thread. But it's just a hunch and I can't prove anything since it's on android.

Comment: Stupid question - does your Android device have more than one CPU core?

Comment: @Sam Very good question. I should have mentioned that. Yes it has four cores.

Comment: You should use **Unity's profiler** to catch the lag moment. Then you will see the main thread's **call stack** which took so long in time to complete the frame.

Comment: @AgentFire The lag happens in my own scripts AND on unity's Camera.Render (according to the profiler). I don't know what unity does but I definitely know what my code is doing. It does the same thing every few frames. And without the worker thread there is no spike. I can't prove it but it seems sometimes the main thread and worker thread are executed on the same CPU. I checked and occasionally It happens on Windows but I can't prove it on android.

Comment: @mortezakhosravi they are all your own scripts. However, the profiler should spot a concrete code line on which the freeze happens. Find the line.

Comment: I wonder if you can determine what core the code is running on, or if you can set the thread affinity? I found some links where people described similar situations: [here](http://miss-cache.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/android-running-native-code-on-multiple.html) and [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-ndk/12a8vdge4t/4-pthreads-same-performance-as-1-pthread-other-cores-not-utilized-tegra-3). Sounds like it's picking the same core as the main thread occasionally.

Comment: @Sam I believe the first link is exactly what's happening. Since it does occur in every unity game that uses threading, a suitable solution should be found to address this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't know if that works in Mono on Android though.

Comment: @Sam That doesn't work but even if it would, it could be platform or even version-specific.

Comment: In my experience working on cross-platform PC and console games multi-threading often does involve platform-specific tweaking. The same issue might not happen on an Intel desktop CPU because it's just more powerful.

Comment: @Sam I couldn't agree more. All of that is true. There is no problem on PC since it's way more powerful and the impact of having main and  background threads on the same CPU would not be very important since usually the CPU has a lot of free time each frame.